# Why does a transaction use a higher gas amount in Mainnet than testnet (Goerli)?

Tags: gas

I am working on a contract that transfers an ERC721 token according to the balance of an ERC1155 for a specify wallet a the moment of executing a transaction like a Claim.

In Goerli testnet the operation in terms of gas uses is approx 101000 but in mainnet the amount is a lot higher than in the testing environment.

Exists a difference between the testnet and mainnet in terms of gas used in a transaction?

Why my transactions fails in Mainnet?

Attached screenshots of the transactions

**Transaction Default in Metamask Mainnet**
[image: Transaction Default in Metamask Mainnet]

**Succesfull transaction in  goerli**
[image: Succesfull transaction in goerli]

**Failed transaction in mainnet**
[image: Failed transaction in mainnet]